# HTTPS site on IIS returns 401, HTTP works

Tags: ssl, iis, iis-10, http.sys

Would appreciate help to figure out why HTTPS bindings on IIS are returning a 401 status code while HTTP bindings for the same site work.

The following screenshot shows what happens when you browse to the HTTPS site:

[image]

The following screenshot shows the bindings:

[image]

The following screenshot shows authentication settings:

[image]

The following screenshot shows file permissions:

[image]

The following screenshot shows IIS version:

[image]

The TLS certificate is from Let's Encrypt but I am getting the same result with the IIS development certificate.

The same problem occurs with static HTML pages and ASP.NET Core application.

HTTP version of the site works but HTTPS returns 401.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit 1 - additional info:**

Failed-Request Tracing feature installed and enabled as shown in the following screenshot but no log file is created when reproducing the problem.

[image]

The following is a screenshot from browser developer tools to see what the response looks like. Not sure why NTLM is being used when it is disabled.

[image]

**Edit 2 - additional info:**

I think the response header "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0" suggests that http.sys is responding to the request instead of IIS.

Comment: Please post the detailed error message about the 401 error. You can ry using FRT to view details about the 401 error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis similar problem: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/iis-client-certificate-authentication-results-in-401/ba-p/1342999

Comment: Thanks @YurongDai  I've updated the question with additional info.

Comment: What identity is your apppool using? ApplicationPoolIdentity? And have you checked the code? What have you set in your code?

Comment: @YurongDai The pool is running as ApplicationPoolIdentity. I have tried to create a standard user account and run it under that account with the same results - http works and https returns 401. I have also tried using static HTML pages by pointing the website to C:\inetpub\wwwroot and the result is the same. I feel that HTTPS requests are not getting to IIS. Something is routing them to http.sys. Maybe it's URL registration or firewall. I don't have enough skills in this area to figure it out myself.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description. You can use the Fiddler tool. Start the Fiddler tool with traffic capture enabled, browse to the IIS web application so it prompts for credentials. In Fiddler, look for the request that caused the 401, and look at the original request and response view. You will also need the IIS logs from the IIS server to confirm the HTTP status and sub-status codes. If you are not very clear, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com, or consult a professional consultant to help you find the cause of the problem.